# Get the index of an element in a queryset

Tags: python, django, indexing, django-queryset

I have a QuerySet, let's call it `qs`, which is ordered by some attribute which is irrelevant to this problem. Then I have an object, let's call it `obj`.  Now I'd like to know at what index `obj` has in `qs`, as *efficiently* as possible. I know that I could use `.index()` from Python or possibly loop through `qs` comparing each object to `obj`, but what is the best way to go about doing this? I'm looking for high performance and that's my only criteria.

Using Python 2.6.2 with Django 1.0.2 on Windows.

Comment: Just for an update, first of all, query set is unordered. So, the index may vary for different iteration. You need to do `order_by` over any field and then following Vinay's answer will help in case if you just need the index.

Comment: If we have 10 million records it is hard operation for database.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

QuerySets in Django are actually generators, not lists (for further details, see [Django documentation on QuerySets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#ref-models-querysets)).
As such, there is no shortcut to get the index of an element, and I think a plain iteration is the best way to do it.

For starter, I would implement your requirement in the simplest way possible (like iterating); if you really have performance issues, then I would use some different approach, like building a queryset with a smaller amount of fields, or whatever.
In any case, the idea is to leave such tricks as late as possible, when you definitely knows you need them.
**Update:** You may want to use directly some SQL statement to get the rownumber (something lie . However, Django's ORM does not support this natively and you have to use a raw SQL query (see [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#topics-db-sql)). I think this could be the best option, but again - only if you really see a real performance issue.

Comment: I see. It has been a while since I last touched SQL, but I figured maybe it would be possible in plain SQL and therefore possible using Django's QuerySet API.

Comment: Yes, that could be an option. I have added it to the possible solutions.

Answer (score 68):

If you're already iterating over the queryset and just want to know the index of the element you're currently on, the compact and probably the most efficient solution is:

```
for index, item in enumerate(your_queryset):
    ...
```

However, don't use this if you have a queryset and an object obtained by some unrelated means, and want to learn the position of this object in the queryset (if it's even there).

Comment: this is not efficient and there is a memory leaking issue since you are looping through every single object in your table from your python code. the most efficient answer is to use a single DB query to get the index which is Richard's answer

Comment: @Amin_mmz This depends on what the poster had wanted. If they're iterating over the queryset, have an object and wonder about its position - `enumerate` is all they need. That was my understanding of the question, and this is why there is no loop body. However, I see that it can be interpreted differently. If they have a queryset and an object they believe to be contained in there - you are correct that iterating over the queryset is an awful idea, and Richard's answer is the correct one. An even better one could be a query that would use SQL `ROW_NUMBER()` window function.

Answer (score 58):

If you just want to know where you object sits amongst all others (e.g. when determining rank), you can do it quickly by counting the objects before you:

```
    index = MyModel.objects.filter(sortField__lt = myObject.sortField).count()
```

Comment: In this case you would also want the `sortField` to be unique, because otherwise you would get the position of the first element with `sortField` equal to `myObject.sortField`.

Comment: Should it not be `.count() - 1`? For example, if there is 1 object in the queryset, the index is 0.

Comment: @DavidD. in that case, the expression will give 0 as the count since the filter is using "less than" not "less than or equal".

Comment: This would be perfect if only `sortfield` is guaranteed to be in incremental/decremental order (in which case, an expected sequence).  Doing this over something like an `id` can yeild unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was what was needed to change some code that I've been trying to make ORM only for quite a while.  (When given a directory name, return the previous (-1) & next (+1) directories in the same directory).  Previously I had it optimized, and was using the list method w/index.  Now I was able to make it entirely ORM based.

Comment: Caution, twohot is correct.  I just ran into this issue.... 
If it's in incremental order (e.g. A, B, C, D, etc) it'll work fine, but if it's in non-incremental order (Z, L, U, B, K, etc) it doesn't.  While the query set is showing the data correctly, it's as if the count is showing the incremental index value, not the actual index of the item.

Answer (score 25):

Assuming for the purpose of illustration that your models are standard with a primary key `id`, then evaluating

```
list(qs.values_list('id', flat=True)).index(obj.id)
```

will find the index of `obj` in `qs`. While the use of `list` evaluates the queryset, it evaluates not the original queryset but a derived queryset. This evaluation runs a SQL query to get the id fields only, not wasting time fetching other fields.

Comment: This may be more efficient or it may be less efficient than just evaluating the original queryset, depending on whether you were going to do that anyway later on (since querysets cache their results).

Comment: There is a problem with this method. qs.values_list('id', flat=True) return different values in each step. You obtain different index with the same query.

Answer (score 9):

It's possible for a simple pythonic way to query the index of an element in a queryset:

```
(*qs,).index(instance)
```

This answer will unpack the queryset into a list, then use the inbuilt Python index function to determine it's position.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using [`queryset.extra(…)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) and some raw SQL like so:

```
queryset = queryset.order_by("id")
record500 = queryset[500]

numbered_qs = queryset.extra(select={
    'queryset_row_number': 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "id")'
})

from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    "WITH OrderedQueryset AS (" + str(numbered_qs.query) + ") "
    "SELECT queryset_row_number FROM OrderedQueryset WHERE id = %s",
    [record500.id]
    )
index = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]

index == 501 # because row_number() is 1 indexed not 0 indexed
```

Comment: @alexche8 it performs well enough for me on result sets in the 10's of thousands (which I paginate afterward)