# How to get next row on a django queryset?

Tags: django

I have a queryset with that will return several rows in it. One of the row has a slug "slug-456", how do I get to the next row after that row having the slug "slug-456" with respect to the current ordering the queryset have?

I can loop through the queryset and check if the current row has the slug "slug-456" and if it has take note that the next row is what I'm after, but Is there a more efficient way?

**UPDATE:**
I did it this way:

```
id_list = list(qs.values_list('id', flat=True))
try:
    next_id = id_list[id_list.index(obj.id) + 1]
    obj = Object.objects.get(id=next_id)
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Querysets are generators so there isn't really a shortcut along the lines of `qs[qs.indexof(slug="..")+1]`. Any solution you come up with still require iterating through the queryset (at least till the target object).

As you mention, a possible way to do it would be to loop through the queryset and return the one right after the one with slug="slug-456".

You could of course take a more convoluted route and do something along the lines of:

```
# get slugs in order
sio = list(qs.objects.values_list('slug', flat=True))
target_slug = sio[sio.index(sio) + 1] # watch for KeyError
your_object = qs.objects.get(slug__exact=target_slug)
```

while amusing to write, this is unlikely to give any performance benefits (unless your model has many fields in which case iterating through the output of `values_list()` first might be beneficial).

Related answer: [Get the index of an element in a queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042596/get-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-queryset/1042651#1042651).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I found my answer there mixed some the last bit from yours.

Comment: I'm staring at this TypeError right now "QuerySet object is not an iterator" after having passed one to the next builtin function.  They are iterable, in that they return an iterator, but the QuerySet itself is not an iterator.

Comment: Indeed, they are not iterators. They're more like generators with additional bells and whistles. To get an actual iterator, use [`QuerySet.iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.iterator).

Answer (score 10):

For py<2.6,

```
queryset.iterator().next()
```

For >= 2.6

```
next(queryset.iterator())
```

should do the trick

Comment: I understand this will get the next item but I still need to point to the exact row first before I can call next() and that's my problem.