# How can i get indexes of my instances objects?

Tags: django, django-models

For example if i want print indexes of this objects:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(depth=1)
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you mean the positional index of each item in the returned queryset, or are you talking about the db indexes set by the model?

Comment: Positional index of each item in returned queryset.

Comment: Check out this [question][1], it seems to be the same.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042596/get-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-queryset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the positional index of a list/iterator of items (like a queryset), you can do something like the following:

```
for i, obj in enumerate(items):
    print i, obj
```

The value of i will be the index of the given model instance.