# Can't modify object by index in evaluated queryset with Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I manage the order of `Documents` in a `Collection` by assigning ordinal numbers to `DocumentMemberships`, which is the model that represents an intersection of a `Document` and a `Collection`. Here is one place that I do this (this is inside a method of `Collection`):

```
memberships = self.membership_set.order_by('document__title', 'document__revision').all()
for i in range(memberships.count()):
    if memberships[i].document.category == 'SDS': 
        memberships[i].ordinal = i + 1000 # push documents in the 'SDS' category to the end
    else: memberships[i].ordinal = i # leave the rest ordered by title and then revision
    memberships[i].save()
```

However, when I inspect the `DocumentMemberships` in the admin interface after running this code, all the ordinals are zero (the default for that field).

I tracked the issue down to the objects in the QuerySet not being properly modified when accessed by index. This is a shell session that more clearly demonstrates the issue:

```
>>> memberships = s.membership_set.order_by('document__title', 'document__revision').all()
>>> memberships.all()
[large number of DocumentMembership objects]
>>> memberships[0]
[DocumentMembership object]
>>> memberships[0].ordinal = 2
>>> memberships[0].ordinal
0
```

The ordinals have to be fully computed as integers before further processing so I can't simply iterate over it. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you use indexing to get an object from a queryset, the object you are getting is a copy of the original, so you are modifiying a copy of the object "inside" the queryset.

If you make this:

```
m = memberships[0]
m is membership[0]
```

you get `False` as a result.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1042664/1029019). Maybe that help you to solve your problem of using the index of an object in the queryset to update an attribute of it.

Hope it helps!