# Index of row looping over django queryset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I used to convert a django query set to a pandas DataFrame before looping over its rows, but it's not efficient as I loose many properties of a query set.

```py
sample_qs = MyModel.objects.all()
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_qs)

for index, row in sample_df.iterrows():
    print(f"Processing row {index} of {sample_df.shape[0]}...")
```

Is there a similar way to iterate over `sample_qs` without converting it to a pandas DataFrame and still have something similar to index?

I know about iterator, but couldn't find anything similar to index:

```py
for q in sample_qs.iterator():
    print(f"Processing {str(q)}...")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the index of an element in a queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042596/get-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-queryset)

See in particular the answer about using `enumerate()` for your use case.

Comment: Thanks @MihaiChelaru